# Embedded Moodle login form does not function

Tags: authentication, iframe, embed, moodle

I would really appreciate any help you can offer as I'm right at the beginning of my learning curve in this area and relatively clueless.

I want to embed my moodle site within my main website and allow users to log in that way. I've used an iframe, so it looks like this on my website:

[image: login iframe embed]

However, it doesn't function, so that if I type in my credentials, the login button does nothing and doesn't take me anywhere.

If I click 'forgot password', I'm redirected to that page within the frame, so the navigation works there- but the login function does not .

I've  set 'allow frame embed' to yes on the Moodle security settings.

What am I missing here?

How can I integrate a functioning 'login' and navigation of moodle from within my own website?

Comment: Maybe set the debugging level to developer and see if it says anything

Site administration > Development > Debugging > then choose Developer level

Comment: Also, can you log into the Moodle site outside of the iframe?

Comment: Have you found a workaround yet? Ive read somewhere that browsers dont allow the use of local storage across domains. Dont know if this might have something to do with it